# In rich:fileUpload, if the user tries to upload an empty file i.e 0 bytes file then how can we display an error popup

Tags: jsf, richfaces

In rich:fileUpload, if the user tries to upload an empty file i.e 0 bytes file then how can we display an error popup

i tried using the onclick="emptyFileCheck();", but the emptyFileCheck() method is not called.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
        function emptyFileCheck()
        {           
            alert("File to be added");
            return "true";
        }
    </script>

<rich:fileUpload onclick="emptyFileCheck();" fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadBean.listener}" id="upload" acceptedTypes="txt,xml,docx,pdf"
                                    ontyperejected="alert('Only txt,xml,docx and pdf files are accepted');" maxFilesQuantity="5" immediateUpload="true"
                                    onsizerejected="alert('Maximum file size allowed is 5MB.');"
                                    addControlLabel="Upload File">
```

Comment: What version of RichFaces are you using? 4.5 lets you deal with this kind of thing on client side, in older version you have to upload the file. (And don't post two questions asking basically the same.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this event: `onuploadcomplete`

This response is based on the rich:fileUpload [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/tlddoc/rich/fileUpload.html)